# Azure Active Directory - Role based Store Manager

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

I need to implement the store based access to web portal. For that we have created the following roles

- Admin
- Store Manager1
- Store Manager2

I am able to implement authorization for Store Manger 1, Store Manager 2. If there are around 500 stores do I need to add 500 roles in active directory since each role has different view?

Comment: You're hitting the role explosion issue. Try using XACML. You can implement a rule that states "manager can view store if store id in list of assigned stores"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like quite a lot of work to make roles for each store. Though you could automate it with PowerShell, to me it seems a bit weird.

You could instead just have a Store Manager role, and then on your app side check which stores they access to. One way would be a relational table with one column being the user's id and the other a store id they have access to. You can query that when you authenticate the user and store the values in claims/session data.

Comment: Thanks @Juunas. This will help.